# UIActivityViewController view frame is cut in ios 9.0

Tags: ios, ios9, uiactivityviewcontroller

I encounter this bug when using UIActivityViewController in order to create a simple UI for sharing assets in my app. This works well on ios 10 and above, but in ios 9 this annoy issue appears. I've already researched for solutions but didn't find any help. Could you guys please take a look?

My code is just simple as below:

```
NSString *url=@"http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/APPNAME/idXXXXXXXXX";
NSString * title =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Download ECG app %@ and get free reward points!",url];
NSArray* dataToShare = @[title];
UIActivityViewController* activityViewController =[[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:dataToShare applicationActivities:nil];
activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypeAirDrop];
[self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:^{}];
```

In ios 9, it looks like [THIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAfLZ.png)

Comment: Are you using this: `self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;` ?. Remove this. This autolayout issue may results into distorted frame.

Comment: A quick fix would be to present the view controller on your navigation controller, as follows. `[self.navigationController presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:^{}];`. Your `self` view controller probably has something funky with it's auto layout, as @pkc456 said.

Comment: Thanks guys, but none of those worked for me. I tried to google search and tried those solutions already.

Comment: An interesting fact that if I set `animated:NO` it displays perfectly, of course without animation, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to update `animated:NO` when you present the Activity View, if the view displayed correctly with `animated:NO` then `self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;` should be the cause of this problem.

Comment: Please make sure to remove `self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;` in whole project.

Comment: I tried it too, nothing happens but ugly UI, #cryariver